# Reference: Vanna, volga, vega approximations

Tags: reference-request, volatility-smile, volatility-interpolation

I am looking for a reference on how to approximate implied volatility in a stochastic model vis-a-vis vanna, volga, vega, and other model parameters, in particular the derivation of such equations and the underlying intuition.

Any good articles/books out there?

Answer (score 1):

I find Dimitri Reiswich's Ph.D. thesis quite useful when it comes to FX smile construction and market conventions. Section 3.3 is on vanna/volga method.

Also have a look at Uwe Wystup's book, especially Section 3.1 "The Trader's Rule of Thump".

**References**

Reiswich, Dimitri (2010) "The Foreign Exchange Volatility Surface", Ph.D. Dissertation, Frankfurt School of Finance & Management

Wystup, Uwe (2006) "FX Options and Structured Products", John Wiley & Sons

Answer (score -1):

perhaps this is what you're looking for? - lookup Mercurio Vanna VOlga
["Consistent Pricing of FX Options
"  this paper derives a formula for the vol smile in terms of atm vol and 25 delta call and put vols](http://www.fabiomercurio.it/consistentfxsmile.pdf)

Answer (score -1):

Here's more references to the vanna-volga method:

- Castagna, Mercurio (2007), The vanna-volga method
  for implied volatilities, [Risk](https://www.risk.net/derivatives/equity-derivatives/1506580/vanna-volga-method-implied-volatilities) [ [Download](http://quantlabs.net/academy/download/free_quant_instituitional_books_/[Risk%20Magazine,%20Castagna]%20The%20Vanna-Volga%20Method%20for%20Implied%20Volatilities.pdf) ]
- Perederiy (2018), Vanna-Volga Method for Normal Volatilities, [arXiv](https://arxiv.org/abs/1810.07457). `Note: As the title indicates, this paper is about the normal volatility`
- [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vanna-Volga_pricing) `Note: also see the references there`